# java integer not working as expected

Tags: java, int

Here is my code 
this should output (8477559501395327) but it is giving(2084842641)
whats the problem here. I tried long instead of int but it gives some different answer

```
    int counter = 0;
    int counter2 =0;
    int k=203903;
    int result=0;
    int countequalk =0;
    int i=0;

   while(true){


        if( i % 2 != 0){
            counter++;
            if(counter<k){
                counter2=counter2+counter;
            }
            //System.out.println(counter+" "+i);

           if(counter>counter2&&counter<=counter2+k){

               result = result+i;
               countequalk++;
           }
           if(countequalk==k){
               break;
           }
        }
        i++;

    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Don't kid yourself. 'Not working as expected': maybe; 'not working correctly', no chance.

Answer (score 2):

The number `8477559501395327` doesn't fit into an `int` - which supports values up to `2^31 - 1`, as specified by `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. try using a `long` instead, which has a maximum value of `2^63 - 1`, as indicated by `Long.MAX_VALUE`. This value is greater than `8477559501395327`, so it fits. For even bigger numbers, better use `BigInteger`.

Comment: Or even better, `BigInteger`.

Comment: Or long unsigned if you know you're staying in the positives.  (I assume Java has unsigned ints, if not it's trivial to implement)

Comment: @MaxvonHippel nope, Java doesn't have unsigned integers.

Comment: Though guava, a common util library, does have helper methods for working with longs as unsigned.

Comment: @MaxvonHippel And no, they are not 'trivial to implement'.

Comment: @EJP I've implemented both before for homework, but considering you know more about Java, I'll assume your point is that they are difficult to implement well (that there are subtleties to doing it *right* that students such as myself likely gloss over)?